# PyCharm won't accept file name

Tags: python, pycharm

I have created a file with a regular name "Track", but somehow in the rush there must have happened some error. I didn't bother reading it in the console, instead quickly did a safe delete (with usage search) and then recreated it.

Now that the file is back PyCharm won't accept it as a Python file (even though it has the .py ending). Completion and Highlighting does not work. Other file names however work.

Recreating it again without safe delete doesn't change anything. How can I make PyCharm accept the file like all the other Python files?

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite understand what happened. Inside a comment in another file there was the word "Track.py" (originally just "Track" but PyCharm apparently added the ".py")

This caused an error for an inexplicable reason. Something relating to word occurrences in other files must have been the issue. After removing the ".py" from the comment refactoring (renaming) worked. And now the file is named "Track" like it should be.

Hopefully this is helpful!